# reduced size image not shown while big image works

Tags: python, django, thumbnails

I really have no idea why it won't work, I did exactly same as other tutorials. Maybe the way I'm extracting image is the problem. I'm using imagekit and goose. Any help would be appreciated. 
Here is my Full Code for this problem .

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):    
     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 

            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))
```

For extract method

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return article.top_image.src
```

my models, where image is saved(has been extracted)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
        processors=[ResizeToFill(70,70)],
        format='PNG',
        options={'quality':60}
    )
```

For post.html

```
<img src="{{ post.image_thumbnail }}" alt="" />            
<img src="{{ post.image}}" alt="" />
```

second img is working, while the first one shows small box showing broken image
I have installed pillow correctly, and

Comment: Try `{{ post.image_thumbnail.url }}`.

Comment: what is the url of that broken image? open the image and see how it looks, broken, wrong url, wrong format... etc ?

Comment: @rinti, that doesn't work. it shows absolutely nothing

Comment: @rinti `.url` brings nothing if the image itself not there

Comment: @doniyor the image is extracted from article(if you see media.py), I can see the image here <img src="{{ post.image}}" alt="" /> but not with thumbnail for somereason

Comment: @haloyoba i am talking about thumbnail one.

Comment: @doniyor yes the image won't even be shown now

Answer (score 0):

according to discussion I had with you in discussion chat, the image url of thumbnail is:

```
<img src="CACHE/IMAGE/http:/imgur.com/lalala/path/to/image.png">
```

which is wrong.

you need to fix the url and possibly also hand image file over to ImageSpecField so it can thumbnail correctly..

Comment: yes but how do I fix these so the problem is solved? I have no idea how to begin to hand image file over to ImageSpecField?